# Previous week data comparison SQL - Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table with sample data as below:

[image]

I am trying to calculate a current weekly data comparison with previous week value, and to make the output as below:

[image]

How can i achieve this:

Answer (score 1):

This should work, just change the "#test" to your table name:

```
SELECT  t2.C_Date,
        SUM(t2.Prod1 + t2.Prod2 + t2.Prod3) AS Total_sale,
        SUM(t1.Prod1 + t1.Prod2 + t1.Prod3) AS Prev_Week_Total_sale
    FROM #test t1
    INNER JOIN #test t2
        ON t1.C_Date = DATEADD(DAY, -7, t2.C_Date)
            GROUP BY t2.C_Date
```

Comment: There's no DATEADD function in Teradata. And if there's more than one row per date your join will be many-to-many and the result totally wrong. Otherwise you don't need SUM.

Comment: With sale_table (C_DATE,Total_sale) as
(SELECT C_DATE,
             SUM(col1 + col2) AS Total_sale
      FROM test1
      GROUP BY 1)      
sel A.C_DATE,A.Total_sale,B.Total_sale as Prev_Week_Total_sale
FROM  sale_table A
      LEFT OUTER JOIN sale_table B
      ON (A.C_DATE=B.C_DATE + Interval '7' DAY)
;